# ImageJ: Help Creating a LOOP that looks through folders and subfolders

Tags: loops, imagej

I am new to using imageJ and creating my own codes, anyways, I am trying to create a loop that runs all the roi's at once, but I am having trouble doing that. So far this is the code I have:

```
input = "S:\\Research Projects\\BAC\\machine training set\\Results_1stRound\\2016Data_1stRound\\epoch_based_training_0.7_TPF=0.615_FP=2.110\\SID130871_9999.330357336093230241152104825447607218951\\"; 
output = input; 

function action(input, output, filename) { 
open(input + filename); 
setThreshold(112, 255); 
run("Create Selection"); 

roiManager("Add"); 
roiManager("Select", 0); 
saveAs("selection", output + filename); 
close(); 
roiManager("Deselect"); 
roiManager("Delete"); 
} 

list = getFileList(input); 
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
        action(input, output, list[i]);
```

What I want the loop to do is to look through all the different SID files that I have so I wouldn't need the specific SID part in the input but I have no idea how to create a loop so that it looks through folders (SID files) and subfolders  to create the rois. As of right now, I have to put the specific SID file in the input, so any help on how I can create a loop that looks through the different SID files at once and then create the rois would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some macro examples and examples on the ImageJ mailing list archive how to iterate over nested folders:

https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/macros/BatchProcessFolders.txt

http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/batch-process-macro-td4469342.html